# I'm trying to test my kernel with the debugger. I want to pass a bytes ticket as an internal transfer. How do I encode this in the inputs.json?

Tags: smart-rollup, rollup, scoru

I'm trying to test my kernel with the debugger. I want to pass a `bytes ticket` as an internal transfer. How do I encode this in the inputs.json? And how do I discover this information? Can i use `octez-codec`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following is an inbox message for a `pair string (string ticket)` kernel type.

```
[
  [
    {
      "payload": "Pair \"tz1Ke2h7sDdakHJQh8WX4Z372du1KChsksyU\" (Pair 0x0172f6de83625d1d2a57c9db6c3dde3b7f479cb53200 (Pair \"The Looking Glass\" 10)"
    }
  ]
]
```

So if you want a ticket bytes, replace "`The looking glass`" with `0x28382...`

The first 0x... Is the byte encoded minter contract hash

Answer (score 0):

The messages in the input file of the debugger can be either :
`{ "external" : <hex encoded bytes> }` or `{ "payload" : "<michelson data>" }` (I'm not sure the encoding is registered in `octez-codec` though).

The encoding itself is in `src/bin_wasm_debugger/messages.ml` , and there's also the format in the documentation: http://tezos.gitlab.io/alpha/smart_rollups.html?#testing-your-kernel (with some examples)